# How do I check if the user chose not to grant my app access after logging in with social media?

Tags: laravel, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I'm following the [Socialite github documentation](https://github.com/laravel/socialite), and the controller method below works just fine if the user successfully logs in with Facebook and grants my app access.

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    dd($user);

    // $user->token;
}
```

However, how do I know if a user selected "Cancel" when Facebook asks for the user's permissions?

Currently, I receive the error below after I click "Cancel" on the Facebook page that asks for my permission to share my info with the app:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111: 
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"Missing authorization code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"H75M4eMC+1f"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code to the following, which did the trick:

```
public function handleProviderCallbackFacebook(Request $request)
{
if ($request->has('code')) {
  $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
  dd($user);
}
else 
{
echo "fail";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the request in callback function. If user choose not to grant access means no request sent to callback function:

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
   if(!$request->all())
   {
      return redirect('login')->with('message','Social authentication cancelled'); 
   }

   $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
   dd($user);

}
```